# Html 5 option tag structure

Tags: html

Does anyone know how to condense option tags to minimize repeating yourself? For example:

```
<select>
  <option selected="selected">(Days)</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>    
  <option>3</option>    
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
  <option>6</option>
  <option>7</option>
```

Is there a better way of going about this that makes more sense structurally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps [`<input type="number">`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/number-state.html#number-state)?

Comment: So using the example I put, I could just use <input type="number"> and then what?

Comment: I'm just a little confused as to how use that. Could you give me a little example of how that works? Sorry, I'm still learning html 5 :D

Comment: That is the example. The complete example. It gives you an input into which you can type a number.

Comment: So it's just going to be <input type ="1"> and so forth then, right? Thanks for the input, I just wanted to know if it could be shortened in any way.

Comment: No. `<input type="number">`. The word number. Not "any old number".

Comment: Okay, but where would I include the numbers though? I'm actually making a drop down menu where you can select hours and minutes. It basically encompasses a clock.

Comment: You wouldn't. The user can type them. Or use the spinner controls that recent browsers add to number inputs.

Comment: You might want to make use of `min` and `max` though: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-input-element-attributes.html#attr-input-max

Comment: Nice I just rendered it I see exactly what you're saying. That's awesome! But now how would I let the user know that's the hours, minutes, am/pm he/she's tampering with?

Comment: `<label>` (probably grouped with a `<fieldset>` and a `<legend>`)

Comment: Sounds like something else I'll have to figure out i'll probably find it on the w3.org somewhere though.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using php you could make a for loop, but your html will still be long.

```
<select>
<? for ($i=1;$i <32; i++):?>
    <option><?=$i?></option>
<? endfor; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: I'm actually going to use Javascript, but you're right I was thinking the same thing. I just wanted to see if there was a way to shorten it.

Comment: Don't use JavaScript to add essential content.

Comment: Oh, I'm not. I'm just using Javascript as the back end and I'm keeping my html, css, and javascript files completely separate from each other.

Comment: well 2 things 1) JAVASCRIPT CAN BE TURNED OFF!! 2) JAVASCRIPT CAN BE TURNED OFF. Yes you can write an entire application in js but you really need to understand the difference of how js and php create elements in the DOM or more specifically php creates elements in the DOM and js adds to the DOM. JS is not designed to create an entire webpage and if you use js to create a webpage you will have a ton of problems. It won't be search engine friendly. Kittens will die etc.

Comment: You're exactly correct, I understand what you were getting at. This application won't be that big at all, I wouldn't even consider it a full on webpage just something similar to an alarm clock.